# Elasticsearch overly large transaction log?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch node that I'm sending process metrics, such as RAM consumed and CPU, load to. I write to Elasticsearch about once every 500ms.

This has been running solidly for a week or two until today. I did some inspection and noticed that my `translog` folder for this index is around `12GB`! There are about 70 170 MB `translog` files in the folder. Each file has a last modified date within five minutes of its predecessor.

Can I reduce that size? Can I keep it from getting that big again? There must be a process to routinely trim the transaction log for an index.

Comment: Have you modified [any of these translog settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html) in your `elasticsearch.yml` file? The default size is 512MB, so 12GB sounds like something is not right.

Comment: Well it's not just one translog. There are about 70 files each one is 170MB inside the translog folder. They're created about every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where this can happen, some are bugs in version 6.x before the current 6.8.x, others are expected if you do rolling restarts/upgrades with heavy indexing at the same time.

See the following links

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/large-translog-files-using-6-0-stack/110375/10
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/huge-transaction-log/74261
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/extremely-large-translog-files-per-shard-in-elasticsearch-6-2-4/174041

General discussion of TransLog with a description of a tool that can truncate the translog is at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/index-modules-translog.html